# Why I can't use an API key from .env file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables

So I have an .env file with api key inside of it:

```
API_KEY = {apikey}
```

And I'm trying to use it in app.js file:

```
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

console.log(API_KEY);
```

And I get the next error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I'm not using node.js so I guess there's some way it couldn't work.

Comment: Exactly, in-browser js has no `process`. You also shouldn't expose API keys to in-browser JS because that way people can steal them. Use your server as a proxy for API requests.

Comment: `process` in NodeJs only like @ChrisG mentioned, so any other environment will throw this (or similar) error.

Comment: i understand, so should i declare my api key straight in app.js file?